# Required Validation on bootstrap date-timepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, bootstrap-datetimepicker, client-side-validation

I have developed  ASP.Net MVC 5  application. In that I am working on client side validation for bootstrap datetime-picker.

I am facing a problem with required validation. Validation is working fine on submit button  but when I , select datetime validation error message should be removed automatically and when I remove the datetime or clear textbox ,it should be display validation error message.

This is model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select from date")]
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
```

This is View

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime" id="datepickerConsFrom">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "pull-left FromDate group", @placeholder = "From", ID = "startdtCons", Style = "width:49%" })
 <span class="add-on fromDate " id="spanFromDate" style="cursor: default"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
 </div>
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromDate, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

Please suggest any  inputs on this..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using clientside Validator with Bootstrap-datetimepicker, you should revalidate the datetime field.

Simply add below code in script

```
$("#startdtCons").on("change", function (evt, params) {
            $(evt.target).valid();
        });
```

its works for me.